# How con match optinal groups if exits?

Tags: regex

I have the following examples strings:

(1-0) **PK-35** - Women

(2-2) **PK-35** Women

(1-0) **Real Betis** - Women

(2-2) **Real Betis** Women

There are ladies football teams and i want capture the name without the genres. Name and genre can be separate or no by a "-".

The capture solution i want are in strong. The problem is with PK-35 because of it have a "-" in the name. My expression is

([\w+\s-]*) ( - )?Women

but in the first expression is matching PK-35 -, because "-" is allow in the first group. How can do it to capture the name without the "-" separation if exist?

Comment: Use `^(\S+)[ -]+Women` and grab capture group #1

Comment: I think it's nice to know if these are part of larger text or is PK at the start of a string? Also, is it always the same pattern: `upperupper-digitdigit`?

Comment: Sorry, but i didnt a very complete answers. There is a lot of strings... that show in the picture. But the problem is when i have a "-" in the name of the group that i want due to the final substring can be "- Femenino" "Femenino" (it's spanish)

Comment: @RobertoA. Can you update the question with the strings from the image and specify what you want and do not want to match?

Comment: I updated with more options.

Comment: @RobertoA. Like this? `\b(\w+(?:-\w+)?) (?:- )?Women\b`  https://regex101.com/r/JIeJyE/1

Comment: Just in case you find it useful: [`(\w[\w\s-]*?)\s+(?:-\s+)?Women`](https://regex101.com/r/nIRZ2q/1/). This pattern will match any amount of whitespace, hyhens or word chars after a word char, capturing that into Group 1, and will stop before the leftmost occurrence of "1+ whitespaces, (an optional `-`, 1+ whitespaces) and `Women`. Another option (if the name cannot contain parentheses): `(\w[^()]*?)\s+(?:-\s+)?Women`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks!!! That's the solution.

Comment: I posted an answer then.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the match specific matching the `-` between word characters instead of repeating the character class with hyphen and whitespace char to overmatch it.

Then match a space and make the following `-` and space optional.

The value is in capture group 1.

```
\b(\w+(?:[ -]\w+)*) (?:- )?Women\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
  - `(?:[ -]\w+)*` Optionally repeat either a space or `-` and 1+ word chars
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?:- )?` Match a space with an optional `-` and space
- `Women\b` Match Women and a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rV9keC/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```java
(\w[\w\s-]*?)\s+(?:-\s+)?Women
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nIRZ2q/1). Details:

- `(\w[\w\s-]*?)` - Group 1: a word char followed with zero or more word, whitespace or `-` chars as few as possible
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?:-\s+)?`  - an optional non-capturing group matching one or zero occurrences of a hyphen and then one or more whitespaces
- `Women` - a literal string.